# Why does forEach return undefined but will log to console

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am trying to iterate over an array and add some HTML tags. I have tried `.map`, but since it returns another array I can see the commas in the HTML. I tried `.forEach` and it works when I log it to the console, but I get undefined in the HTML. I searched for an answer to this and found a couple answers pointing to no return to the calling function. Some had a callback and were returning from the call back but not to the calling function. I can't find where I'm not returning.

I know `wrapTag` is returning since I can log it to the console, but it doesn't seem to be passed to `wrappedItems`.

Is there a return I'm missing or is it something with `.forEach` that I'm not implementing correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let objR = {
    key1:"5",
    key2:"8",
    key3:"6",
    key4:"9",
    key5:
        {subKey1:"1",subKey2:"2",subKey3:"3",subKey4:"4"}
}

let arr = [];
let html = '';

const s = x => document.getElementById(x);
const isObject = val => (typeof val === "object") ? true : false;

const keyValueToArray = (obj) => {
    for(let key in obj) {
        let value = obj[key],
             n = [];

        if(!isObject(value)){
            n.push(key, value);
            arr.push(n);
        }
        else{
            arr.push(key);
            keyValueToArray(value);

        }
    }
    return arr;
}

const typeCheck = (x) => {
    console.log(typeof x);
    return x;
}

const wrapTag = (item, tag, i) => isObject(item) ? '<' + tag + '>' + item[0] + ' : ' + item[1] + '</' + tag  +'>' 
                            :'<' + tag +'>' + item + ':</' + tag +'>';

//const wrappedItems = keyValueToArray(objR).map(x => wrapTag(x, 'li'))

const wrappedItems = keyValueToArray(objR).forEach(function(x, i, z){
    var res = wrapTag(x, 'li');
    console.log(res);
    return res;
})

html = '<ul>';
html +=  wrappedItems;
html += '</ul>';
console.log(`html = ${html}`);


s('cards').innerHTML = html;
```

});

I made `forEach` work by wrapping it in an anonymous function and using `let` to declare `res`. I had to pass in `obj` to the `wrappedItems` function, but that's not far from what I was trying to achieve.
Here's the revised function.

```
    const wrappedItems = (obj) => {
        let res = '';
        keyValueToArray(objR).forEach(function(x, i, z){
        res += wrapTag(x, 'li');
        console.log(res);
        });
        return res;
        }

    html = '<ul>';
    html +=  wrappedItems(objR);
    html += '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` doesn't return anything so `wrappedItems` is undefined. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). You might try `map()` instead:

```
keyValueToArray(objR).map(function(x, i, z){}
```

Or push to a new array inside `forEach()`

EDIT:

Once you've mapped the values you can make them into one string without commas using `join()` like this:

```
html +=  wrappedItems.join(" "); // or whatever you want to join with (maybe "\n")
```

This should give you:

```
<ul><li>key1 : 5</li> <li>key2 : 8</li> ...
```

Comment: I tried `.map`, as you can see in my code it's commented out, I get commas in my HTML since it returns an array. I was trying to do this without using a `for - in` loop.

Comment: @jwolf Oh yeah, I skipped the comment -- sorry about that. See edit.

Comment: I'll try that, since it's cleaner than my solution above.

Comment: The `.join(' ')` is what I was missing. I did it a little different so I make the code more generic. `const wrappedItems = (obj) => keyValueToArray(obj).map(x => wrapTag(x, 'li')).join('');`